# Is "Azure Database for MySQL servers" cloud service based on a Windows or a Linux environment?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, azure, azure-database-mysql

I have a Windows Server production environment hosted on-site and I would like to have a separate development environment hosted in a cloud service. Amazon Web Services host their RDS MySQL server in a Linux based environment. This differs from the MySQL implementation in the Windows environment with the main issue being [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). So I would like to find a cloud service that hosts in a Windows environment so it would be most similar to my production environment. After looking through the Azure documentation for *Azure Database for MySQL servers*, I could not find an answer. I would like to not spin up an entire Windows Server VM when I could use a more cost effective cloud service.

Comment: [lower_case_table_name 0 support (Allow Case Sensitivity)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597982-azure-database-for-mysql/suggestions/33805897-lower-case-table-name-0-support-allow-case-sensit#{toggle_previous_statuses}) Azure for MySQL supports lower_case_table_names 1 or 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is “Azure Database for MySQL servers” cloud service based on a Windows or a Linux environment?

As you said that you can't find it in the Microsoft documentation.

So I asked Azure Support and they replied that:

**Azure Database for MySQL is running in a Windows Server machine rather than a Linux machine. Per discussed offline, Azure PostgreSQL single server is running in a Windows Server machine as well while Azure PostgreSQL Hyperscale (Citus) is running in a Linux machine.**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hit `SHOW VARIABLES;` command, and observe `version_compile_os` property. This will let you know the underlying operating system.

[image]